# Calling part of a  variable in a user defined function

Tags: function-construction

I have defined a function

```
logicalInputField[i_, fieldSize_, numberOfFields_, enable_,tx_,symbol_] :=
Column[{InputField[Dynamic[tx[[i]]], Number, ImageSize -> fieldSize, 
Enabled -> enable, ContinuousAction -> True],
  Dynamic[If[TrueQ[tx[[i]] == ""],                   
     (symbol[[i]] = "Please Enter"),(symbol[[i]] ="Right")                                                                           
  ]  ]}]
```

I am calling this function here.

```
DynamicModule[
{s = {}},
 For[i = 1, i <= 3, i++,
     With[{i = i},AppendTo[s, logicalInputField[i, {50, 20}, 3, True,{"", "", ""}, {"Please Enter", "Please Enter", "Please Enter"}]]]];
     Panel[ Row[s]]]
```

I want to ask whenever I am not giving tx and symbol as an argument at the time of defining function. and then calling it, it works fine. But, as soon as I enter some value in `InputField` , it gives error message

```
Set::setps: {, ,} in the part assignment is not a symbol.
```

Why? How can I call the `Part` of a variable from the user defined function.

Comment: I don't understand the code very well… but I think a semicolon is needed before `Panel`.

Comment: @xzczd: This code is just a sample but I want to ask how can I call the Part of the list. Here symbol and tx are the lists. So, how can I call these variables from the function. I guess this is a wrong way of calling. Therefore, I am getting error.

Comment: I think I get one of the point: `If[TrueQ[tx[[i]] == ""],                   
     (symbol[[i]] = "Please Enter"),(symbol[[i]] ="Right")                                                                           
  ]`doesn't give back a value.`symbol[[i]] =`should be deleted here.

Comment: @xzczd: yes. It gives the value when both the arguments tx and symbol are removed from the defined functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem can be boiled down to the following:

> In programming language like python I can define a function like this:
>
> ```python
> def test(x):
>    x[0]=2
>    return x
>
> test([3])
> #The out put is [2]
> ```
>
> But in *Mathematica*
>
> ```
>  f[x_] := (x[[1]] = 2; x)
>  f[{3}]
> ```
>
> outputs `{3}` with the warning `Set::setps`, why? I expect `{2}` to be the output!

It's because, unlike in language like python, once a function is called in *Mathematica*, the arguments in function body will be immediately replaced by the expressions sent into the function as arguments. This can be proved by:

```
f[x_] := (y = x; Print@Hold@y; Print@Hold@x)
f[{2}]

    (*=> Hold[y]

         Hold[{2}]*)
```

The problem can be solved by using intermediate variables in the function, here is a quick fix:

```
logicalInputField[i_, fieldSize_, numberOfFields_, enable_, tx_, symbol_] := 

(txtx = tx; sysy = symbol; 

 Column[{InputField[Dynamic[txtx[[i]]], Number, ImageSize -> fieldSize, 
                    Enabled -> enable, ContinuousAction -> True], 
         Dynamic[If[TrueQ[txtx[[i]] == ""], 
           (sysy[[i]] ="Please Enter"), (sysy[[i]] ="Right")]]}])
```

This isn't the end. By avoiding global intermediate variables, `For` loop and unnecessary `symbol`, we can make the code sample cleaner:

```
logicalInputField[i_, fieldSize_, numberOfFields_, enable_, txa_] := 
 DynamicModule[{tx = txa}, 
  Column[{InputField[Dynamic[tx[[i]]], Number, ImageSize -> fieldSize, 
     Enabled -> enable, ContinuousAction -> True], 
    Dynamic[If[TrueQ[tx[[i]] == ""], "Please Enter", "Right"]]}]]

Panel[Row[Table[
   logicalInputField[i, {50, 20}, 3, True, {"", "", ""}], {i, 3}]]]
```