Symbol in Global Context but List in Module and Block?
Can someone explain the principles underlying the following behavior.
I define the list testD, and then use a Do loop to change values in the list (I realize there are smarter ways but they don't fit the real problem)
testD = {11, 12, 13, 14};
Do[testD[[i]] = testD[[i]] + 1, {i, 1, 4}]

What I really need is a reusable function so I refactor as follows:
ftest1[d_] := Module[{},
    Do[d[[i]] = d[[i]] + 1, {i, 1, 4}]; 
    Return[d]
]

This makes Wolfram angry and I get the message:
Set: {12,13,14,15} in the part assignment is not a symbol.

After some thought I realize the d[[i]] is not being treated as a symbol, as was the case when it wasn't scoped by Module. So I change to:
   ftest2[d_] := Module[{d}, 
       data = d;
       Do[data[[i]] = data[[i]] + 1, {i, 1, 4}]; 
       Return[data]
    ]

   ftest2[testD]

This now works. My question is whether I should have expected Module and Block to have treatedd[[i]] as a list and why - what are principles I am missing here!

Read this: How to modify function argument?.

You said "this now works", but just to be sure I wanted to point out that testD will not be modified when you evaluate ftest2[testD].

You will want to do something like SetAttributes[ftest2,HoldFirst]

Sorry I missed the Return[ ] statement.

I corrected the last function by swapping data and d.

Thanks everyone, you're right there are answers elsewhere on this stackexchange, however @lericr provides an explanation of the principles underlying the passing of arguments. I knew what was wrong not why. I edited the question accordingly.

The "why" part is explained in the linked post, too. Please read the answers therein carefully. Notice it's not a "Symbol in Global Context but List in Module" issue, it's evaluation order issue. What you've encountered is essentially the following: {1,2,4}[[1]]=566

Another strongly related (if not duplicate) post: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10448/1871


Can someone explain the following behavior

There should be lots of explanations of this on this site, and this is also covered in the documentation. But since it's such a stumbling block, maybe yet another explanation can't hurt.
Mathematica is essentially an evaluation engine. It's a very different computational model compared to most other languages. But, there are various mechanisms that have been specially created as exceptions so that certain things that people are used to in other languages can be done in Mathematica. One of those special exceptions is using Set on Part expressions. Consider this example...
myList = {1, 2, 3, 4};
MapAt[1 + # &, myList, 3]
(* {1, 2, 4, 4} *)

myList
{1, 2, 3, 4}

The MapAt created a new structure based on the input myList. But it didn't do this by referencing myList as a variable and then looking up its value. No, the evaluation engine evaluated all of the arguments to MapAt before MapAt started working. MapAt never "saw" the symbol myList. All it "saw" was the actual concrete list {1,2,3,4}. And as you can see, myList was indeed left unchanged.
I introduced that just to show a typical way to update myList, which would look like this:
myList = MapAt[1 + # &, myList, 3]
(* {1, 2, 4, 4} *)

myList
(* {1, 2, 4, 4} *)

For whatever reason, Wolfram decided to introduce a mechanism that mimicked more "mainstream" variable update constructs. There are limitations to how far this can go and still maintain the core idea of expression evaluation, but the Set+Part mechanism is allowed:
(* Reset myList and start over *)
myList = {1, 2, 3, 4}
(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)

myList[[3]] += 1
(* 4 *)

myList
(* {1, 2, 4, 4} *)

I actually think this is kind of weird given Mathematica's core "identity".
So what happened in your code?
ftest1[d_] :=
  Module[
    {},
    Do[d[[i]] = d[[i]] + 1, {i, 1, 4}];
    Return[d]];
ftest1[myList]
(* error messages and an unchanged list *)

When you call ftest1[myList], you're not feeding the variable myList into the Module. Before anything happens, the argument myList is evaluated (resulting in {1,2,3,4}), and so you're effectively calling ftest1[{1,2,3,4}]. Next, the value {1,2,3,4} is bound to the symbol d, and so everywhere that d shows up is replaced with {1,2,3,4}. Then the evaluation engine kicks in and it eventually encounters {1,2,3,4}[[1]] = {1,2,3,4}[[1]] + 1. But you can't use Set to assign a value to something like {1,2,3,4}[[1]], so the update fails.
This is an unfortunate consequence of allowing the Set+Part construct. People assume that such expressions are working just like "normal" programming languages, and then they run into these gotchas.
One fix is to do your element updates on a temporary structure and then do a wholesale reassignment:
ftest1[d_] :=
  Module[
    {tempD = d},
    Do[tempD[[i]] = d[[i]] + 1, {i, 1, 4}];
    tempD];
myList = ftest1[myList]

Another fix would be to use the various mechanisms available to interrupt the normal order of evaluation. As @DanielLichtblau pointed out, you could set the HoldFirst attribute on your function so that the argument isn't evaluated immediately. That would allow you to grab the symbol itself and operate on it. (Set itself has the HoldFirst attribute, which is how it can do its magic.)
I assume that this example is a simplified version of your real situation, but just in case... A simpler way to do this would be:
myList = 1 + myList

There's no need for the whole Module + Do loop approach.
